# Django wrong encoding in admin interface

Tags: python, django, encoding, django-admin

[Wrong encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4wXc.jpg)  in admin interface but I dont understand why. In project [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae4Bl.jpg) is set utf-8

My `admin.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.contrib import admin
from main.models import file_record

class FilesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['file_name', 'owner', 'date']


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(file_record, FilesAdmin)
```

Comment: Try `DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'` and `DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/html'` which are the defaults, already.

Comment: check `LANGUAGE_CODE` in settings

Comment: It works! Thanks for help!